# PostgreSQL Calculate product of an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Write a function that takes an array and returns the product of all the other elements for each element. For example, f([2, 3, 4, 5]) -> [3x4x5, 2x4x5, 2x3x5, 2x3x4] -> [60, 40, 30, 24].

I know to calculate product you can do exp(sum(ln(value))) but am unsure on the rest.

if someone could help it would be appreciated.

Comment: is it possible that the array contains duplicates?

Comment: Edited it so its fixed and not stars instead "x"s and let's assume there are no dupes. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is one solution using just SQL Select. It first generates a `prep` table in a form

```
rn  | num   | arr
1   | 2     | {2,3,4,5}
2   | 3     | {2,3,4,5}
3   | 4     | {2,3,4,5}
4   | 5     | {2,3,4,5}
```

the arrays are then unnested and we generate an intermediate result in the following form (table `t`)

```
rn  | num   | x
1   | 2     | 3
1   | 2     | 4
1   | 2     | 5
2   | 3     | 2
2   | 3     | 4
2   | 3     | 5
...
```

Such intermediate result is grouped and we calculate the required product. The final step is a creation of an array from rows (the `array_agg` function)

```
create aggregate product(integer)
   (stype=bigint,sfunc=int84mul,initcond=1);

create function product_array(p_array int[])
returns int[]
as
$$
declare
    r int[];
begin
    select array_agg(p) into r
    from (
        select product(x) p 
        from (
            select row_number() over () rn, 
              num, 
              p_array arr 
            from unnest(p_array) num
        ) prep,
        lateral unnest(arr) x
        where num != x
        group by rn, num
        order by rn
    ) t;
    return r;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
immutable;

select product_array(array[2,3,4,5]);
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0c7097d67149449a4d698d6a5f6a955a)

Product is computed by an aggregate function `product` defined at the beginning of the script since there is no such function in PostgreSQL.

The SQL contains the `row_number` function in order to preserve the order of the elements of the input array since the SQL switch to relations from arrays and back.

Comment: It should only be in post gres

Comment: @DGDATA I do not understand your comment. The solution is for Postgres (see the demo) ...

Comment: CAn you put it in a function please

Answer (score 1):

While it's doable with with SQL, I think in this case PL/pgSQL might be easier to deal with:

```
create function multiply_elements(p_input int[])
  returns int[]
as
$$
declare
  l_result int[];
  l_idx1 int;
  l_idx2 int;
begin
  for l_idx1 in 1..cardinality(p_input) loop
    l_result[l_idx1] := 1;
    
    for l_idx2 in 1..cardinality(p_input) loop
      if l_idx1 <> l_idx2 then 
        l_result[l_idx1] := l_result[l_idx1] * p_input[l_idx2];
      end if; 
    end loop;
    
  end loop;

  return l_result;  
end;
$$  
language plpgsql
immutable;
```